# calculate distance between two points using arcore unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, distance, area, arcore

Trying to build an application,to calculate distance between two touch points using arcore unity.How should I perform scaling from screen coordinates to real world co-ordinates.

I came across free asset called distance tool but it doesn't calculate real world distance between two points

Comment: Is it a 3D world?  Then what point do you mean? -- there's a whole ray of points that each touch could be.

Comment: Yes,it is a 3d real world,by points I mean for example finding distance between two points on a table by providing touch inputs

Comment: You can use [`ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) to get the ray associated with the touch, and then use [`Physics.RayCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to intersect that ray with the objects in your scene.

Comment: Once you have both 3D points simply use `Vector3.Distance`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert screen coordinates to world coordinates using [Camera.ViewportToWorld](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html)

It takes viewport coordinates which are basically normalized screen coordinates, they range from 0 to 1. For example if your resolution is 1920x1080 and your screen coordinates are 960, 540 then your viewport coordinates will be 0.5, 0.5. You can find your resolution with Screen.width and Screen.height.

The camera function will return a world point and from there you can use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

to calculate the distance between the world points.